# Qual melhor valor para o memory_limit do PHP com 4GB de memória?

Tags: php, memory-limit

Tenho um *server cloud* dedicado, com 4GB de RAM e 4 Cores de 1.2GHz.

Tenho um sistema extremamente robusto rodando e gostaria de saber a quantidade de memória a setar em `memory_limit` no PHP 5.5?

Comment: Já teve problema com valor padrão? vc pode setar um valor diferente do padrão do php.ini direto no script para os casos mais críticos.

Comment: Não tem mais nada no servidor? Banco de dados?

Comment: @perdeu, eu sei onde. O problema é o cálculo para estimar o uso de memória para o PHP.

Comment: @bfavaretto, não, apenas PHP rodando neste server. Obrigado! ;-)

Answer (score 1):

No scripts que possuem um lógica mais robusta, onde o consumo de memória é maior, insira o seguinte, para realizar testes e saber o consumo de memória que um usuário tem em seu servidor, e multiplica isso pela quantidade de acessos simultâneos que seu sistema geralmente possui.

> // Iniciamos o "contador"
>
> list($usec, $sec) = explode(' ',microtime());
>   $script_start = (float) $sec + (float) $usec;
>
> /* SEU CÓDIGO PHP */
>
> // Terminamos o "contador" e exibimos
>   list($usec,$sec) = explode(' ', microtime());
>   $script_end = (float) $sec + (float) $usec; $elapsed_time = round($script_end - $script_start, 5);
>
> // Exibimos uma mensagem
>
> echo 'Elapsed time: '. $elapsed_time. ' secs. Memory usage: '. round(((memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024) / 1024), 2). 'Mb';

- Veja mais em: http://blog.luders.com.br/desenvolvimento/calculando-o-tempo-de-execucao-com-php/#sthash.AVooB9EP.dpuf